# Timeline webpart load event - SharePoint Server 2019 Classic Page

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part

Is there any event available in SharePoint to know when a timeline webpart gets loaded into the page?

Timeline webparts are rendered after a few seconds of page load.

My page contains multiple timeline webparts, and I want to call a JS function once all these are rendered. Currently, I am using setTimeout(); but doesn't feel like a good approach.

Any suggestions?

[image]